# How to implement an AVL tree without storing height inside the node?

Tags: java, data-structures, avl-tree

I am currently learning binary search tree. For a school assignment, I want to implement an self-balancing binary search tree (I choose AVL tree); however, the Node class cannot be modified. I cannot use the common implementation of the AVL tree (I can't store height inside the node).
This is the source code that I implemented (using HashMap).

```
public class Tree {
    static class Student {
        String id;
        String name;
        public Student(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {return id + ", " + name;}
    }
    
    private class Node {
        Student e;
        public Node lc, rc; // left child; right child

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public Node(Student data) {
            this.e = data;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    Node root;
    public HashMap<Node, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   
    public void insert(Student s) {
        root = insert(root, s);
    }

    public Node insert(Node curNode, Student s){
        if (curNode == null){
            Node newNode = new Node(s);
            map.put(newNode, 1);
            return newNode;
        }
        else if (s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) < 0)
            curNode.lc = insert(curNode.lc, s);
        else if (s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) > 0)
            curNode.rc = insert(curNode.rc, s);
        else return curNode;
        int l, r;
        map.put(curNode, max(nheight(curNode.rc), 
                nheight(curNode.lc)) + 1);
        
        int balance = getBalance(curNode);

        if (balance > 1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) < 0)
            return rightRotate(curNode);
        if (balance < -1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) > 0)
            return leftRotate(curNode);
        if(balance > 1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) > 0){
            curNode.lc = leftRotate(curNode.lc);
            return rightRotate(curNode);
        }
        if(balance < -1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) < 0){
            curNode.rc = rightRotate(curNode.rc);
            return leftRotate(curNode);
        }
        return curNode;
    }
    

    public int max(int a, int b){
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }
    
    public int nheight(Node curRoot){
        if (curRoot == null) return 0;
        return map.get(curRoot);
    }

    public int getBalance(Node curNode){
        if (curNode == null) return 0;
        return nheight(curNode.lc) - nheight(curNode.rc);
    }
    
    public Node rightRotate(Node y){
        Node x = y.lc;
        Node T2 = x.rc;
        x.rc = y;
        y.lc = T2;
        map.put(y, max(nheight(y.lc), nheight(y.rc)) + 1);
        map.put(x, max(nheight(x.lc), nheight(x.rc)) + 1);
        return x;
    }

    public Node leftRotate(Node x){
        Node y = x.rc;
        Node T2 = y.lc;
        y.lc = x;
        x.rc = T2;
        map.put(x, max(nheight(x.lc), nheight(x.rc)) + 1);
        map.put(y, max(nheight(y.lc), nheight(y.rc)) + 1);
        return y;
    }
    
}
```

I tried using a HashMap<Node, Integer> to store the height of each node, and using recursive method to calculate the height and balance factor every time. For small number of nodes, the above two methods would work; however, for large node size (>=1000000) those methods will not work. Is there any other data structures I can use the keep track of the height of each node?

This is the code I used to test. I randomly created 1000000 students with names and ids and insert them into the AVL tree.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    String[] surnames = {"Chan", "Leung", "Li", "Lai", "Cheung", "Yeung", "Tang", "Chow", "Fung", "Tsang", "Kwok", "Chu", "Liu", "Wong", "Mak"};
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    String[] names = new String[1000000];
    for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
                a.append((char)('a' + random.nextInt(25)));
            }
            names[j] = surnames[random.nextInt(surnames.length)] + " " + a.toString();
    }
    int id = 22222222;
    for (String name : names) {
        id += random.nextInt(100);
        tree.insert(new Tree.Student(String.valueOf(id), name));
    }
}
```

}

The code works fine when the size of the String is 1000 (String[1000]). It gets error when the size of String gets larger. For example, when it gets to 1000000. The error code is below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "lc" because "y" is null

Comment: The common AVL implementation does not store height in the node, but (only) a balance factor. I don't understand why a HashMap would not work? The memory needs for that hashMap are O(n). That hashMap should deliver the balance factor. You don't need height at all. What is the problem?

Comment: @trincot I have added some source code and test code. Hopefully, it will help you understand the problem better.

Comment: Try to find a smaller case where you get the same error, and then use a debugger to inspect where things go wrong. You seem to assume it has to do with the *size* of the input, and that somehow a hashMap breaks down, but that is very unlikely given the error message you got, which is just a NPE.

Comment: @trincot You are correct. The problem is not likely to be the size of the input. I tested the code with the same input multiple times, sometimes it would work, and sometimes it would not. There has to be something wrong with the rotation. I am still trying to figure it out. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found. A careless mistake. I was focusing too much on the size of the input. The actual problem is with the insertion and rotations.
The amended code.

```
public Node insert(Node curNode, Student s){
        if (curNode == null){
            Node newNode = new Node(s);
            map.put(newNode, 1);
            return newNode;
        }
        else if (s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) < 0)
            curNode.lc = insert(curNode.lc, s);
        else if (s.name.compareTo(curNode.e.name) > 0)
            curNode.rc = insert(curNode.rc, s);
        else return curNode;
        int l, r;
        map.put(curNode, max(nheight(curNode.rc), nheight(curNode.lc)) + 1);

        int balance = getBalance(curNode);

        if (balance > 1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.lc.e.name) < 0)
            return rightRotate(curNode);
        if (balance < -1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.rc.e.name) > 0)
            return leftRotate(curNode);
        if(balance > 1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.lc.e.name) > 0){
            curNode.lc = leftRotate(curNode.lc);
            return rightRotate(curNode);
        }
        if(balance < -1 && s.name.compareTo(curNode.rc.e.name) < 0){
            curNode.rc = rightRotate(curNode.rc);
            return leftRotate(curNode);
        }
        return curNode;
    }
```